# Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I uploaded my web application (Spring + Hibernate) on the server (Tomcat 7 - jdk 1.7) and I got this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
```

In my computer, I have the same configuration (Spring,Hibernate, Tomcat 7, jdk 1.7, same libraries etc.) and everything works.

I looked into the internet and someone says that I need to add the `hibernate.cfg.xml`, but I never used it on my computer, and everything worked perfectly.

This is what I have in my Spring configuration file:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />            
</bean>     

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>             
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.jeansedizioni.model"/>            
</bean>   

 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />  
      <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />  
      <property name="username" value="${db.user}" />  
      <property name="password" value="${db.pass}" /> 
</bean>  

 <bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
     <property name="locations">
        <list>
           //here are user, pass etc. for the database
           <value>classpath:database.properties</value>                 
        </list>             
    </property>   
</bean>
```

Does anybody know what's my mistake?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a `hibernate.dialect` property to your `database.properties` file

example:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

And add `hibernateProperties` to your `sessionFactory` bean declaration to be like this :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>             
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.jeansedizioni.model"/>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
    </props>
  </property>            
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this property inside your `<bean id="sessionFactory">`:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
    </props>
</property>
```

Then in your configuration file(where u are fetching user,pass,url) mention the dialect as shown below:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```